# What does the Hungarian burn victim shout at Jack Baer?

Tags: dialogue, translation, the-usual-suspects

There is an early scene in *The Usual Suspects* (@ 20m40s) where FBI agent Jack Baer visits a burn victim in the hospital. The victim starts talking in "not English" (we later learn it is Magyar), getting more worked-up as he goes. Near the end of the scene, he shouts something like:

> Latima Keyser Söze! Ne mertas! Keyser Söze! Keyser Söze! Latima Keyser Söze! <coughing>

The burn victim is Arkosh Kovash. The police take special interest in him because Baer recognizes the name "Keyser Söze" amid the rest of his shouting.

What does Arkosh actually say? I'm asking for as much of his dialogue in that scene as can be recovered, not just the snippet I tried to reproduce here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Partial, as I'm still looking, but I did find this:

[https://web.stanford.edu/~landy/UsualSuspectsHungarian.html](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Elandy/UsualSuspectsHungarian.html)

> ...what you'll currently find on the web -- via wiki answers, imdb, etc. -- is based on the shooting script, *not on what is actually said in the movie*.

> ... *the following is what Arkosh Kovash really says.*

> **Arkosh Kovash:** … that I live. You… you fool, don’t you understand what I’m saying? If you don’t understand… he kills everyone. I know that man… I know what he looks like.  Can’t you understand me?  But you can see I don’t speak English!  Listen to me!  I saw his face!  If you don’t bring someone right away they will kill me.  I saw Keyser Söze! **[Láttam a Keyser Söze-t!]** Don’t you understand?! **[Te nem értesz?!]** Keyser Söze!!

> **Arkosh Kovash:** They will kill me **[meg engemet]**, don’t you understand?  I saw the devil! **[Én láttam az ördögöt!]** I saw him **[láttam]**... saw him face-to-face **[szemtöl-szembe láttam]**... I will be killed **[meg fognak gyilkolni]**... I saw the devil **[én láttam az ördögöt]**... saw him face-to-face **[szemtöl-szembe láttam öt]**.

> **Translator:** Who is this devil? **[Ki ö ez ördög?]**  Who did you see?

> **Arkosh Kovash:** Keyser Söze.  I saw him.  It was him at the harbor.  He was the one who killed everyone. ... I saw his face... I am seeing it when I close my eyes now.

> *Incidentally, we both think that "ördög" is a very nice word for devil.*

Note:

> *(He also tells me that the name Ákos Kovács -- spelled that way -- is actually quite common: something like the Hungarian equivalent of "John Smith.")*

Also, this:

> I'd like to know what the Hungarian mobster in "The Usual Suspects" (1995) is saying.

https://www.reddit.com/r/hungarian/comments/l6fb3w/id_like_to_know_what_the_hungarian_mobster_in_the/

Hungarian:

> the best I can do for now.

> ..hogy nézz ki. Lattam az..??..ki nem érted? Úgy hogyha élek. Te bolond ember. nem értesz meg engemet? Hogy ha nem ért meg, hozzál valakit aki..??.. Gyilkolt mindenkit. Tudom ezt az embert. Tudom hogy hogy nézz ki. Nem értesz? Tudod hogy nem is én beszélek angolul? Hallgass rám! Láttam az arcát neki. De nem most be..??..mindjárt meg..??.. láttam a Keyser Söze. Nem értesz?! KS. KS. Láttam a KS. Láttam a szemét. Soha nem fogok elfelejteni. ...és itt van segiteni téged. ..??.. tudni mi történt a kikötőbe?

> Ott voltunk egyik pasost* megvenni. Az akartunk venni Magyarországra. Ez a pasos* ismertad*. Az ördögöt. Ö* dolgozott vele. megölnek engemet. Nem érted? Én láttam az ördögöt! Láttam. Szemtől a szembe láttam. Engemet gyilkolni. Én láttam az ördögöt. Szemből a szembe láttam öt. Ki ez ez Ördög? Kit láttál? KS. Én láttam. Ö volt lent a kikötőbe. Ö gyilkolt mindenkit. Láttam az arcát. Úgy láttam minden. Láttam a szememen amikor becsuk mostan. ..??.. Mondj nekem hogy nézze ki az ördög. Én láttam a tűzben..

English:

> ..how he looks. I saw..??.. ki* you don't understand. ..so it is, if I’m alive. You stupid man. Don't you understand me? If you don't, bring someone who..??.. He killed everyone. I know this man. I know how he looks. Don't you get it? Don't you know that I don't speak english? Listen to me! I saw his face! *(This next part is right, but I couldn't understand him)* if you don't bring someone soon they will kill me. I saw Keyser Söze! Do you not understand? KS. KS. I saw KS. I saw his eyes. I will never forget them.

> *(*  ***És itt van***  *is “and here is” so it sounds like “and here is to help you” which is incorrect, but we’ll pretend what’s being said is “we’re here to help you.”* ***Itt vagyunk, hogy segiteni tèged*** *)* Could you tell us what happened at the harbor? We were there to buy one “pasos”*(I think this means guy. I dont think it means dope)*. We wanted to take it/him to Hungary. This is a guy you know. The devil. He worked with him. They’re going to kill me! Don't you get it? I saw the devil! I saw him. I saw him face to face *(from eye to eye)*. He is going to kill me. I saw the devil. Face to face I saw him.

> Who is this devil? Who did you see? KS. I saw him. He was down at the harbor. He killed everybody. I saw his face. It’s like this I see always *(I can't stop seeing it)*. Even now I see it when I close my eyes. ..??.. Tell me what this devil looks like. I looked into the flames...

Notes from translater, AlolanBoomer:

> *There were things he definitely DID NOT say that the dude translated. And the whole translation felt shifted.*

> The Usual Suspects (1995) Hungarian Translation

Both links above reference the first link.

*(edited to include the other translation offered in the reddit link (in case that link dies))*

Comment: After the first cut (after 1:21 in the video) he says "_We were there together to buy a bloke_ [unclear if he means bribe or literally buy]. _We wanted to take him back to Hungary. This bloke knew the devil. He had worked with him_". Original Hungarian: "_Ott voltunk együtt [egy?] pasast megvenni. Haza akartuk vinni Magyarországra. Ez a pasas ismerte az ördögöt. Ő dolgozott vele_". Then the start of your second quote from the link is inaccurate, "_meg engemet_" is actually "_megölnek engemet_" which does mean "_they will kill me_". His grammar is a bit faulty in many places.

Comment: Oh, and the guy's name is probably supposed to be Ákos Kovács. Kovács means Smith and Ákos is an old Hungarian male given name.